# How to make artificial underflow/ overflow?

Tags: javascript, integer-overflow

I'd like to clamp calculations in the range of 0-360 in my program. I know if you have an 8-bit integer adding 255 + 1 will overflow to 0 and likewise, 0 - 1 will underflow to 255.
I wrote this function as a test:

```
//only for negative numbers
function clampTo360 (a) {
  if (a < 0) {
    var b = 361 + a;
    if (b > 0) {
      return b;
    } else {
      clampTo360(b);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to code a function so the calculation 0 - 1 will return 360?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the modulo operator here. However, underflowing inputs will result in negative values.

To avoid that you can add `360` to get a number in the interval `[0; 720)`, and apply the modulo operator again to get a result between `0` and `360`:

```js
function clampTo360(g) {
    return (g % 360 + 360) % 360
}
console.log(clampTo360(720))
console.log(clampTo360(360))
console.log(clampTo360(-360))
console.log(clampTo360(-720))
```

Comment: Ahh nice, just saw this from the mdn article on remainder! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add 360 for getting a positive value and return the remainder.

```js
function clampTo360(g) {
    const rest = g % 360;
    return rest < 0 ? 360 + rest : rest
}

console.log(clampTo360(365));  //   5
console.log(clampTo360(-5));   // 355
console.log(clampTo360(700));  // 340
console.log(clampTo360(-700)); //  20
```

Comment: Note that this won't work with values less than `-360`...

Comment: Right that'll be great for positive numbers, is there a universal solution for getting underflow as well? Or would the best be to just add that function to my clampTo360 function?

Comment: `((g % 360) + 360) % 360`, also see the [mdn remainder article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)